# Implementing a mixed-type list in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write a mixed-type list so it can hold integers and strings on the same list.
I have a customType class that can hold one integer and one string.
When I add items to my list, the add function puts elements to the appropriate variable.

```
public class customType {
    private String str="";
    private int integer=0;
    private String type="";
    private Object NumberFormatException;

    public customType(int integer){
        this.integer=integer;
        type="INTEGER";
    }

    public customType(String str){
        this.str=str;
        type="STRING";
    }
}
```

Since the parameter type of add function is different, I can overload it.

```
public class customTypeList {

private ArrayList<customType> elements = new ArrayList<customType>();

.
.
.

public void add(String str){
    elements.add(new customType(str));
    }

public void add(Integer integer){
    elements.add(new customType(integer));
    }
}
```

But I can not define a get function because the only return type is different and Java is not allowing overload for only different return type functions.

```
public int get(int i){
    return elements.get(i).getInteger();
    }

public String get(int i){
    return elements.get(i).getStr();
    }
```

I know, I can use two ArrayLists for this, but I want to implement a mixed-type list like this.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How do you know whether what you're getting is supposed to be an int or a String?

Comment: It's not possible, actually I'm not sure you could provide any of this methods because the generic list also has method `customType get(int index)`.  Thus, all you can do is to provide methods like `getAsInt / getAsString`

Comment: It's called "overloading" not "overriding" what you do there with `add` and `get`, besides `get`, i.e. method overloading on return-type, not being possible.

Comment: Why would you every want to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example create a "raw" list, that is a list that accepts objects of type `Object`

```java
new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Then, when you want special handling of Integers or Strings, you'd have to use the `instanceof` operator to check if the object is an Integer or a String and cast it accordingly.

```java
if(object instanceof Integer) {
  Integer i = (Integer) object;
}
```

A second approach would be to create different methods for each type of object. I.e.:

```java
public int getInteger(int i);
public String getString(int i);
```

Comment: I forget that I can create new ArrayList<Object>(); Then I realized It wasn't that useful after all because I still need to define other variable types accordingly when I need to use the list. So I guess this is not the java way of doing things.